# how can i replace value 'True' of a dictionary to 'pos' or 'neg'

Tags: python, nlp

I've started recently learning python and i am trying to classify a list of words into : positive 'pos' and negative 'neg'

the result that i'm looking for is :

```
('joli': 'pos', 'bravo': 'pos', 'magnifique': 'pos')
('arnaque': 'neg', 'désagréable': 'neg', 'mauvais': 'neg')
```

I have the following code:

```
def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])


vocab_positif = [ 'joli', 'bravo', 'magnifique']
vocab_negatif = [ 'arnaque', 'désagréable','mauvais']


positive_features = [(word_feats(vocab_positif), 'pos')]
negative_features = [(word_feats(vocab_negatif), 'neg')]
```

output :

```
({'joli': True, 'bravo': True, 'magnifique': True}, 'pos')
({'arnaque': True, 'désagréable': True, 'mauvais': True}, 'neg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be written in a better way if more context was given but this solution matches your desired output I believe.

```
def word_feats(words, val):
    return {word: val for word in words}


vocab_positif = [ 'joli', 'bravo', 'magnifique']
vocab_negatif = [ 'arnaque', 'désagréable','mauvais']

features = {}
positive_features = word_feats(vocab_positif, 'pos')
negative_features = word_feats(vocab_negatif, 'neg')

print(positive_features)
print(negative_features))
```

**Output:**

```
{'joli': 'pos', 'bravo': 'pos', 'magnifique': 'pos'}
{'arnaque': 'neg', 'désagréable': 'neg', 'mauvais': 'neg'}
```

If you want, you can combine the `dict`s such as:

```
combined = {**positive_features, **negative_features}
```

or something like:

```
features = {}
features.update(word_feats(vocab_positif, 'pos'))
features.update(word_feats(vocab_negatif, 'neg'))
print(features)
```

Comment: The desired output was listed first, the current output was listed last. You provided a different way to get the current output.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I noticed late but fixed it.

Comment: @DS_Tn Don't forget to mark one of the solutions as an answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the output you are looking for:

```py
def word_feats(words, desc):
    return dict([(word, desc) for word in words])

vocab_positif = [ 'joli', 'bravo', 'magnifique']
vocab_negatif = [ 'arnaque', 'désagréable','mauvais']

positive_features = word_feats(vocab_positif, 'pos')
negative_features = word_feats(vocab_negatif, 'neg')
```